# Floating an image over another one issue css

Tags: html, css

I am using `relative` and `absolute` position but it doesn't work. what's my mistake?

[image: Here is the snap shoot]

[image: Here is what i want.]

My HTML code:

```css
.slide-item {
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide-item img {
  display: block;
}

.slide-item .sale {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-item">
  <div class="sale">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
  </div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="arr-img" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain your problem, and what you have tried more?

Comment: i want pink sale image float over green image but it was clipped

Comment: There is no pink or green image in your example. Please use example images (from https://placeholder.com for example) in the correct sizes  so we can see your problem.

Comment: From what I see in your CSS, the negative top margin could be moving your image out of the relative container, and if you get and overflow hidden rule, it will clip your image as in your example

Comment: Add overflow:visible to the container (slide-item). Plase update snippet using placeholder images!

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted, here it is with real images: https://jsfiddle.net/hv90fxpj/. something else is causing an interaction. use the element inspector and check the computed CSS.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow thank you, maybe it caused by slick slider, I will check it again... Thanks everyone.

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn that's extremely likely -- i'm not familiar with slick slider, but any 'carousel' or image slideshow will almost certainly use `overflow: hidden;` so that the user can't see the image that's just about to slide into view.

Comment: Thanks alot. This is my silly mistake. i forgot div above has `margin-bottom:100px;` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .slide-item {
            text-align: center;
            height: 400px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .slide-item img:nth-child(2){
            position: relative;
            width: 1150px;
            height: 600px;
            left: 65px;
            top: 25px;
        }

        .slide-item img {
            display: block;
        }

        .slide-item .sale img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 150px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="slide-item">
        <div class="sale">
            <img src="img/icons8-round-128.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <img src="img/111713927-green-screen-green-background-green-screen-stock-footage-video.jpg" class="arr-img" alt="">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```